# Spring Boot OIDC Client Development Through VS Code Not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, openid-connect

So, I am utilizing this [java OIDC client](https://github.com/curityio/spring-boot-oauth-client).

I can get it to run with their suggested `./gradlew bootRun`.

However, I want to debug the source code in VSCode, and cannot seem to do that.

I get this error in VSCode:

[image]

I did not modify this `build.gradle` at all (except for the java version used). Here is what it looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


group = 'io.curity.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Do I need to have some extra configuration somewhere since it's development environment?
Looking at the [Gradle Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html) it seems like the build.gradle should be configured correctly.

Is there a special Gradle command I need to run when working with local development, as opposed to "prodcution" environment.

I am running the application in Debug by simply running "Debug" in VSCode on the main function
[image]

Doing that gives me this error though:
[image]

I can "Proceed", but that doesn't seem to correctly run the application as I am not able to successfully navigate to http://localhost:8080 to see the main index page of the application.

This is the output in my terminal when just proceeding
[image]

I should note that I'm new to Java and Gradle, in general. I have C#/.NET bakcground.
Thanks

Comment: 1. The gradle wrapper is broken/not existent in that project/git repository... (so gradlew is a bad choice/ is a quick fix, once reported) 2. The "problems" your screen shot is showing, are not real problems, but normal and vanish after a "priming" build.

Comment: @xerx593 Can you explain what a priming build involves?

Comment: sry, cannot reproduce: when i open the project initially in intelliJ, (the wrapper binaries get downloaded...maybe this was the root of your problem... firewall, company network,...) and the (priming) build succeeds (with jdk 11).

Comment: ..for me the run/test fails due to other reasons (where the build (compiling & packaging) is successful), mainly due to `https://idsvr.example.com/oauth/anonymous` ...  and "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: idsvr.example.com".

Comment: Thank you. But, I still am unsure what you mean by priming build. What steps do you do to perform this "priming" build you're speaking of.

Comment: Hmm okay, it's weird. But I got it working in VSCode all of a sudden.But, I can't say for certain what how I was able to successfully get it to work. Al of a sudden I see the necessary dependencies in my project